# C# задание на наследование

Tags: c#

Как следует объявить класс, от которого нужно запретить наследование? (C #)

```
a) readonly class D
{/ * Class members here * /}
b) protected class D
{/ * Class members here * /}
c) public sealed class D
{/ * Class members here * /}
d) public virtual class D
{/ * Class members here * /}
```

Comment: Только вариант `c` с ключевым словом `sealed`, `readonly` - не допустим для создания классов, только `struct` - структур. А `virtual` не работает на классы и структуры, только на свойства, поля и методы.

Comment: но по сути правильний ответь должен бить А ?

Comment: Вы читать умеете? `readonly` недопустим для создания классов, как это может быть `a`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если класс объявлен с модификатором [sealed](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sealed), то от этого класса нельзя наследовать и создавать производные классы. Например:

```
sealed class Smth
{
}
```

Comment: ну а какой будет правильний из вариантов

Comment: @jekii вариант "а" правильный

Comment: Как может быть вариант `a` правильный, когда ключевое слово `readonly` не допустимо для создания классов, только для структур или свойств, полей.

Comment: а что тогда  должно бить ?

Comment: @jekii точно не "d"

Comment: а какой должен бить

Comment: @jekii вам же сказали `sealed`, можно поставить галочку на этом ответе в знак благодарности автору